# Error when importing cv2 on anaconda prompt but it is working on jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda

I am importing libraries that I installed using `pip install` to Jupyter Notebook using the anaconda distribution, which is working. Next, I am trying to import the same libraries in the anaconda command prompt and running it. I am getting this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: Can you share the list of packages in the environment?

Answer (score 0):

try these things:

1. First check if you are able to see your library by this command:
   $ pip list or conda list
2. if not available install this module:
   $ pip install opencv-python or conda install opencv-python
3. But before that, try to check numpy module is available or not. If numpy is not available, then install this first.
   $ pip install numpy
4. If all of them exist then, Uninstall opencv-python and numpy first and upgrade your pip using the below command.
   $ pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: While I am upgrading pip it throughs an error like could not install packages due to an environment error.consider using '--user' option or check the permission

Comment: try this:
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip , if this doesn't work try below one :

$ python -m pip install --user --upgrade pip

Comment: Still I am getting error that  no module named cv2 after doing the above steps. I reinstalled pip,numpy,opencv libraries.opencv is working in jupyter notebook but getting error while I am running in anaconda prompt please resolve my problem.it is important to continue my project I am stuck over here

Comment: Check your anaconda navigator environment if it has OpenCV environment different than base, then in anaconda command prompt, you write $ conda activate opencv-env. . This will change your environment and error should not come.

Answer (score 0):

Two options to install cv2 with the latest conda & python3:

1. Open the Anaconda Prompt and switch to your environment:
   `$ conda activate myenv`
   Then install opencv from the menpo channel:
   `$ conda install -c menpo opencv`
2. Open the Anaconda Prompt with admin permission and make sure you're in the base environment:
   `$ conda activate base`
   Then install opencv from the menpo channel:
   `$ conda install -c menpo opencv`

Reconnect your notebook to the kernel to import cv2.